# Use linq to break up list<t> into lots of list<t> of n length?

Tags: .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split an IEnumerable<String> into groups of IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349491/how-can-i-split-an-ienumerablestring-into-groups-of-ienumerablestring)

I have a list that I would like to break into groups of 10.

If I have an object

```
List<Person> allPendingPersons
```

that is of length m.

Is there an elegant way in LINQ to break up allPendingPersons into one or more List objects that all have a up to 10 Persons?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 var groups = allPendingPersons.Select((p, index) => new {p,index})
                               .GroupBy(a =>a.index/10 );
```

if you want to process `IGrouping<,>`. If you are looking for List> back you could try

```
var listOfLists = allPendingPersons.Select((p, index) => new {p, index})
    .GroupBy(a => a.index/10)
    .Select((grp => grp.Select(g => g.p).ToList()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: not the most efficient, GroupBy will buffer all elements and build the lookup. Thus, memory+cpu overhead + not a steaming solution

Comment: Moreover, this will create n lists of 1 element each. Not 10.

Answer (score 52):

You can write your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int size) {
    List<T> partition = new List<T>(size);
    foreach(var item in sequence) {
        partition.Add(item);
        if (partition.Count == size) {
            yield return partition;
            partition = new List<T>(size);
        }
    }
    if (partition.Count > 0)
        yield return partition;
}
```

I [explored this in more depth](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nested-iterators-part-2.html) in my blog.

Comment: slightly better to do: `partition = new List<T>(size);`

Comment: @nawfal: You're right; fixed.

Comment: this is so good! I used it directly on my list of items that needed action on. foreach (var b in senders.Partition(threshold)) { handleBatch(b); } 
simple and elegant, thanks!

Comment: Starred this Q because of your smart A. ;)

Answer (score 7):

The [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads) has an extension method that does exactly what you want:

```
var buffered = allPendingPersons.BufferWithCount(10);
```

If you want to do it using LINQ you could do this:

```
var buffered =
    allPendingPersons
        .Select((p, i) => new { Group = i / 10, Person = p })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Group, x => x.Person)
        .Select(g => g.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

These should be of some assistance.

[How can I split an IEnumerable<String> into groups of IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349491/how-can-i-split-an-ienumerablestring-into-groups-of-ienumerablestring)
[Divide a large IEnumerable into smaller IEnumerable of a fix amount of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172390/divide-a-large-ienumerable-into-smaller-ienumerable-of-a-fix-amount-of-item)
[Can I improve these Pagination extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030246/can-i-improve-these-pagination-extension-methods)
[Get groups of 4 elements from name value list using LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686497/get-groups-of-4-elements-from-name-value-list-using-linq-in-c)
[LINQ: Get min and max values of sequence of numbers divided into subsequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030172/linq-get-min-and-max-values-of-sequence-of-numbers-divided-into-subsequences)
[LINQ Partition List into Lists of 8 members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773403/linq-partition-list-into-lists-of-8-members)

One very popular answer is to check out Jon Skeet's [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), in particular, the `Batch` function, which not only does what you are asking for, but also lets you specify a return selector!

Comment: +1 for MoreLink's `Batch`, [see source here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most efficient technique, but this will produce an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Person>>` sequence, with each inner sequence containing ten elements:

```
var query = allPendingPersons.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Group = i / 10 })
                             .GroupBy(x => x.Group,
                                      (k, g) => g.Select(x => x.Value));
```

And if the result really does need to be a list-of-lists rather than a simple sequence then you can create a `List<List<Person>>` instead by adding in a couple of `ToList` calls:

```
var query = allPendingPersons.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Group = i / 10 })
                             .GroupBy(x => x.Group,
                                      (k, g) => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToList())
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: You can simplify your first version a little bit by writing `x => x.Value` instead of `(k, g) => g.Select(x => x.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try an iterator block:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<Person>> AsGroups(this List<Person> persons)
{
    var buf = new List<Person>(10);
    for (int i = 0; i<persons.Count i++;)
    {
        buf.Add(persons[i]);
        if (i%10 == 0 && buf.Count > 0)
        {
           yield return buf;
           buf = new List<Person>(10);
        }
    }
    yield return buf;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an elegant way in LINQ

The [elegant way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/420534/8155) is not very performant.  Here is a more performant way...

```
    public static List<List<T>> Chunk<T>(
      this List<T> theList,
      int chunkSize
    )
    {
        if (!theList.Any())
        {
            return new List<List<T>>();
        }

        List<List<T>> result = new List<List<T>>();
        List<T> currentList = new List<T>();
        result.Add(currentList);

        int i = 0;
        foreach(T item in theList)
        {
            if (i >= chunkSize)
            {
                i = 0;
                currentList = new List<T>();
                result.Add(currentList);
            }
            i += 1;
            currentList.Add(item);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can be more performant than that by writing an iterator.  See my answer.