# Order list by value with maximum sequence appearance

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following list (simplified):

```
Name | Brand
Shirt0 | Adidas
Shirt1 | Nike
Shirt2 | Adidas
Shirt3 | Adidas
Shirt4 | Erima
Shirt5 | Nike
```

I want to order it by *Brand*, and display (a maximum of) two of a brand in sequence.

Therefore I would not display all 3 Adidas products first, but only two!

Result:

```
Shirt0 | Adidas
Shirt2 | Adidas
Shirt1 | Nike
Shirt5 | Nike
Shirt4 | Erima
Shirt3 | Adidas
```

So it takes two products from every brand, and starts over when no more available.

Any ideas how to achieve this with LINQ?

Comment: I don't think you mean `List<T>` when you say "list", because you have two columns of data instead of just one. So which data structure are you using?

Comment: Maybe it's a `List<T>` where `T` is an object with 2 (or more) properties?

Comment: @Tim Yeah I just thought of that

Comment: I do have `List<T>`, with a `Product` POCO, therefore `List<Product>`

Comment: What if you had 4 Adidas and one Erima? Should it be "A A E A A" or "A A A A E"?

Comment: @dcastro The first one!

Comment: Can I assume that "Shirt0" is kind of product identifier, so it is unique in the list ?

Comment: In fact my Product has a lot of properties (including ArtNo and Name), and also a unique identifier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `Product` class has something like the following property:

```
public String Brand { get; }
```

I would use the following approach:

1. Group products by `Brand` property
2. Wrap the result in each group in an anonymous class with additional `Order` property and assign it 0 if the index within the grouping is less than 2 and 1 if else (will apply for the first and second item)
3. Apply the order based on the `Order` property of our anonymous class
4. Select the product, so we get rid of our anonymous wrapper class

The query below:

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Brand)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new { Order = i < 2 ? 0 : 1, Product = x }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
    .Select(x => x.Product)
    .ToList();
```

I suppose there may be a better approach, but this one is straight from head.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, thanks so much! And produces the same result as the answer from @Rhumborl

Answer (score 2):

Using the ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215512/1901857) you can group the items with each brand into indexes, then order by index and brand and join back into a single list:

```
var results = products.GroupBy(p => p.Brand)
    .SelectMany(pg => pg.Select((p, index) => new { Value = p, Index = index/2 }))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Index).ThenBy(a => a.Value.Brand)
    .Select(g => g.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was searching for :) @danyloid submitted the same approach (but earlier), therefore I had to give him the checkmark, sorry :-S