# Select a group of n objects into a list of a list of objects

Tags: linq

I have Object A in which I have lengths.  I would like to order by length descending, then I would like to group them by threes and return that list of a list of objects.

I can get the grouping to work, but all i get is the key of the grouping and not the items.

```
public class a
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

List<a> c = Instantiate a list

c.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
.Select((e, i) => new { Item = e, Grouping = (i / 3) })
.GroupBy(x => x.Grouping)
.Select(x => x.Key)
.ToList()
```

I think it has something to do with my group by but I cant seem to get it to work.  What I would like is a `List<List<a>>` that have at most three items.

Comment: as I understood correctly, just turn .Select(x => x.Key) into .Select(x => x.ToList())

Comment: also, i / 3 will break your collection into 3 pieces, to partition by length you may look at answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215469/use-linq-to-break-up-listt-into-lots-of-listt-of-n-length#5215506

Comment: @Victor, that is what I'd like.  At least for now I'd like to just simply break into groups of three when it is sorted by length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `.Select(grp => grp.ToList())` instead of `.Select(x => x.Key)`.
This will return the group as a `List<a>`.

Comment: I would add to this that he probably wants `.GroupBy(x => x.Grouping, x => x.Item)`. This will produce a list of lists of `a`s, whereas what he's got now will produce a list of lists of objects of that anonymous type created in the first `Select()`.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will generate a list of lists where the inner list contains three items:

```
var listOfTriplets = c.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
    .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
    .ToList();
```